# How do we verify if the UI message pump is intact for a UI desktop application in a Dump?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windbg, win32-process

I have a WPF application that seems to hang/freeze in a Terminal Services session. I have a memory dump of the freeze CPU and Memory parameters are all fine. I see that dispatcher thread in the executing stack and the same thread is the runaway thread. All the other threads are pretty much waiting for single or multiple objects.

How do I see if the UI thread is intact or if the message pump is fine? I see the below info (native stack is not resolving):

```
0:000> !runaway

User Mode Time
Thread       Time
 0:5bd4      0 days 0:02:03.864
 4:5624      0 days 0:00:01.606
 2:3754      0 days 0:00:00.468
10:580c      0 days 0:00:00.046
15:2ec8      0 days 0:00:00.031
19:57d4      0 days 0:00:00.015
32:8acc      0 days 0:00:00.000
31:6eb8      0 days 0:00:00.000
30:5914      0 days 0:00:00.000
29:8a7c      0 days 0:00:00.000
28:8c14      0 days 0:00:00.000
27:5188      0 days 0:00:00.000
26:8d14      0 days 0:00:00.000
25:3ee8      0 days 0:00:00.000
23:8eb0      0 days 0:00:00.000
```

...

```
0:000> !clrstack

OS Thread Id: 0x5bd4 (0)
Child SP       IP Call Site

0016efc0 763278d7 [InlinedCallFrame: 0016efc0] 
0016efbc 5c09bbb4 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_CLRtoCOM(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef, IntPtr, Int32, Int32, Int32 ByRef)
0016efc0 5c07b294 [InlinedCallFrame: 0016efc0] MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods+ITfMessagePump.GetMessageW(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef, IntPtr, Int32, Int32, Int32 ByRef)
0016f030 5c07b294 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.GetMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef, IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
0016f06c 5c079fe1 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
0016f0b8 5c079d09 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
0016f0c4 5c073df3 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
0016f0d4 5982d3df System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
0016f0e0 5982d037 System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
0016f104 5982cdd2 System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
0016f114 0543c572 BCCFContrib.CompositeUI.WPF.ApplicationShellApplication`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Start()
0016f124 0543bcbc Blaze.Chk.Client.ClientCtrler+CabApp.Start()
0016f13c 04cc46ce Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.CabApplication`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Run()
0016f150 04cc455f Blaze.Chk.Client.ClientCtrler.RunApplication()
0016f180 00563eff Blaze.Chk.Client.ClientCtrler.RunCore()
0016f1d4 00561278 Blaze.Chk.Client.ClientCtrler.Run()
0016f1e0 005611eb Blaze.Chk.Client.ClientCtrler.RunCtrler()
0016f1e8 00561071 Blaze.Chk.Client.ClientCtrler.Main()
0016f374 63043de2 [GCFrame: 0016f374]
```

The callstack seems to be having GetMessage and other message pump related functions. Does that tell that message pump is intact?

Comment: Even if your application is consuming Windows messages, it may still be in an endless loop. Unfortunately you can't see the Windows messages themselves in a user mode dump. You would need a kernel mode dump.

Have you checked for deadlocks in other threads, e.g. by SOSEX !dlk or analyzing the dump in DebugDiag?

Comment: Yup I have tried dlk syncblk and also the native locks,cs . No results . I dont think it is a synchronization issue. After a closer review of all the threads there seem to be some antivirus threads in couple of dumps . Internet tells me that in some scenarios antivirus can cause issues. Additionally This is running in a terminal services environment .

Comment: Perhaps its worth to take a look at WPR/WPA. WinDbg is just a point in time while WPA allows a more holistic view of the system over time. You will not get the memory detail that WinDbg offers but stacktraces and verifying what a thread is waiting on is certainly possible. I can recommend the screencasts by Andrew Richards and Chad Beeder on the subject on Channel 9

Comment: [Defrag Tools: #43 - WPT - Wait Analysis - Channel 9 - MSDN](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fchannel9.msdn.com%2FShows%2FDefrag-Tools%2FDefrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis&ei=v4r1VL7ZM8v8UMjsgqAF&usg=AFQjCNGVZWCtDTPmlaKyGT28xh3Kzhn7_w&sig2=ngbnpScLb8G6jVUKPoWgtw&bvm=bv.87269000,d.d24)